# python with selenium: existing id webelement returns cannot be located

Tags: python, css, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use python with selenium to make an auto login to the following site:
https://www.smartschool.co.il/

I am using Python 3.9.11
Chrome ver 117.0.5938.92 - 64 bit
ChromeDriver 117.0.5938.92 - 64 bit

This is the web element for the username:

```html
<input id="u" type="text" class="text" tabindex="1" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="$('usernameFake').value=$('usernameFake_').value=this.value;return true" autocapitalize="off">
```

Now, this is my code:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

usernameStr = 'XXX'
passwordStr = 'XXX'
url = "https://www.smartschool.co.il/homepage.aspx?page_id=20"
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0'
driver_path = "C:\Gil\smartschool_login\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe"
chrome_service = Service(driver_path)
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')


browser=webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=chrome_options)
browser.get(url)

time.sleep(5)
element = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#u').send_keys("mytext")
```

No matter what i try, i always get the error "**no such element: Unable to locate element**":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Gil\smartschool_login\weblogin_version2.py", line 23, in <module>
    element = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#u')
  File "C:\Users\Gil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 855, in find_element      
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\Gil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 428, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Gil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response 
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#u"}      
  (Session info: chrome=117.0.5938.92)
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7104D7892+54818]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF710446AC2]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7102FDA3B]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF71033E4FC]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF71033E67C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF710379627]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF71035EAEF]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7103775A2]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF71035E883]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF710333691]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7103348D4]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF71083B992+3610402]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF710891860+3962352]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF710889D4F+3930847]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF710573646+693206]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF710451628]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF71044D934]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF71044DA62]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF71043E113]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFE58477344+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFE58B026B1+33]
```

I trying to use the `WebDriverWait` method and it gave me the same error. Website loads pretty fast.

What am i doing wrong?

I have tried few things:

1. To wait for the website to load. But got the same error.
2. To find the element using `browser.find_element(By.ID, "u").send_keys("mytext").send_keys("mytext")`

None of them worked - got the same error.

Comment: Check for presence of `IFRAME` or `shadow-root`

Comment: After installing selectorsHub chrome plug in to analyze the CSS of the page, i stood on the textbox, clicked on it  and selectorsHub gave me the following comment: "Alert: This element is inside iframe. Switch inside iframe to access it through automation"

Answer (score 1):

issue solved!

Indeed, using the selectorsHub chrome plugin it really helped me.

The iframe of which the textbox resided in, was indeed not selected. Therefore the textbox element could not be located.

here is my code correction (in relation to original code):

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src='https://www.smartschool.co.il/login.aspx']")))
element = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#u').send_keys("mytext")
```